# nginx прокси для nodeJS

Tags: node.js, nginx

У меня гостевая машина с установленным Debian GNU/Linux, ip-адрес вот такой `10.0.2.15`.
Я хочу поставить nginx + nodeJS. Мне нужно настроить прокси так, чтобы когда я ввожу любой адрес кроме `10.0.2.15/node` отдавалась статика посредством nginx, а когда я напишу `10.0.2.15/node` запрос попадал на node.

Вот конфиг `nginx.conf`, в директиве `http`:

```
server {
    #ip:порт который будем слушать
    listen 10.0.2.15:80;

    #перенаправление на NodeJS
    location /node {
        #ip:порт nodeJS
        proxy_pass http://10.0.2.15:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    #всё остальное отдает nginx
    location / {
        #путь к каталогу веб сервера
        root /home/dirtez/www;
    }
}
```

Всё работает, если набираю например `10.0.2.15/index.html` - нормально(есть ли файл есть), `10.0.2.15/foo` - 404 (файла нет, всё правильно). И node работает, если набрать `10.0.2.15/node`. Но проблема в том что он работает, если набрать и `nodes` и `nodeasdas`, также `node/sdad`, также `nodeasd/asd`.

Как сделать чтобы node запускался только при `10.0.2.15/node`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно написать `location = /node` тогда только для запросов к /node, второй вариант: `location /node/` - но в последнем я не уверен.

Comment: Первый вариант работает, большой спасибо. Второй не пробовал :)

Comment: Просто в документации http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location все примеры `location` со слешом на конце

Comment: В случае с location = /node запросы типа /node/some-data/goes/here не будут попадать к Node.js. Если это не критично, то можно оставить так. А если подзапросы нужны, то лучше добавить слеш.